Why are $y = \sqrt{1 - y} \cdot x$ and $y=\int_0^x \sqrt{1-y}\ dx$ the same?
$y = \sqrt{1 - y} \cdot x$
$y=\int_0^x \sqrt{1-y} dx$
When I plotted these 2 equations, they were the same. I'm not sure why.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome to MSE! <> The first might be viewed as an implicit equation defiing a plane curve, but is the second supposed to be an integral equation for $y$? Can you perhaps edit the question to say how exactly you "plotted" these?

I've just edited your question. That second one : $\int^x ... dx$, is that correct?

The second equation isn't very clear to me. Usually, you shouldn't have the same variable ($x$) in the limits of integration and in the "$dx$", so I don't know what it means.

The expression under the integral comes outside, and the integrand is $1$. The result is what is on the LHS.

@Sambo That is indeed confusing which is why it should never be done, but really the two occurrences of $x$ are just two different variables, one bound by the integral and one free, that both happen to have the same name. It would be the same as if it were $\int_0^x... {dt}$.

@Dominique yes, though the x in dx is not the same as the x at the top of the integral.

@HarryWang: pardon my directness, but you are using the same name for different things inside one equation? NEVER DO THAT!!!

Important note: You shouldn't use the same variable in the limits, and in the $dx$. So your equality/equation/integral does not actually make sense. However I will try to demonstrate why your plotting software probably showed the same for both.
Since the integrand in $y=\int_0^x \sqrt{1-y} \: dx$ is independent of $x$, we can treat it like a constant.
So $y =\int_0^x \sqrt{1-y} \: dx = \sqrt{1-y}\cdot x \: |_{x=0}^{x=x} = \sqrt{1-y}\cdot x$
Which is equivalent to your first plot.
(Here the evaluation $x=x$ is why you shouldn't use the same variable in the limits, and in the $dx$)
